# javascript splice causing lag in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a simple running game where platforms scroll from right to left. These platforms are stored in an array, and when they are off screen I use array.splice(index, 1) to remove it. This however is causing an ever so slight lag on the exact second splice is called. I have also used Array.shift() but I can still see the slight dip in frame rate as this is called. Is there a better way to remove/destroy something?

```
for(var x = 0; x < platforms.length; x++){
    var platform = platforms[x];

    platform.x -= 10;

    if(platform.x + platform.width < 0){
        platforms.shift();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to debug code we can't see?
Please add a short code snippet that reproduces your problem to the question.

Comment: This code snippet doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code added doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: This question could probably get an answer on gamedev.stackexchange.com. Anyway, the best way to solve a problem is avoid having it. You could just not remove items from the array, use a fixed size array instead (large enough to store all the items you need) and flag as canceled the items you don't want to render anymore. You could reuse those "canceled" slots later.

Comment: If, for some reason, there's so much going on that a splice would affect the drawing of the canvas you could just try and re-use each element instead of removing it. Alter the position of each element on it leaving the canvas so that it is back at the 'beginning' ready to go again? You may benefit from mimicking a multithreaded concept here (I'm not sure on this though). If you know how long it takes for an element to 'leave' then you could utilise a `setInterval` to do the clear up job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shift and splice are "slow" functions. They possibly rebuild your whole array.

Imagine having an area with 1000 items. A shift could possibly be 'create a new array with all items, except the first'. If your first 100 items now result in a shift, you rebuild 100 arrays, with 900-1000 items, which will result in about 100.000 inserts, 100 new array allocations.

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == ....)
    {
        var newArray = new Array(array.length - 1);
        for(var o = 1; o < array.length; o++)
            newArray[o - 1] = array[o];
        array = newArray
    }
}
```

worst case scenario, with a length of 1000, this will result in:

```
for ( i = 0 to 1000 )
    for ( o = i to 1000 )
        recreate the array
```

so that would be 0.5million iterations and recreations of the array. While this could be fixed with either 1 iteration (dynamicly sized array) or with 2 passes (fixed sized array):

```
// dynamic size
var newArray = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] != ....)
        newArray.push(array[i]);
}
array = newArray;

// fixed size 
var cnt = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i] != ....)
        cnt++;
var newArray = new Array(cnt);
for(var i = 0, o = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i] != ....)
        newArray[o++] = array[i];
array = newArray;
```

and another simple optimization for your for loops (which obviously wont work if you modify the array in the for loop):

```
for(var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++)
```

(yes, i am aware that some numbers may be off. but it gets the point across.)

Comment: would love to have some javascript ninja correct me here though. This is all based on stuff i used to program in other languages.

Comment: Actually it's not a matter of "rebuilding the whole array". The point is that operating on the size of an array could trigger *garbage collection*.

Comment: good point. a way to avoid that is keeping items referenced and removing them after the mainloop. So flag them first, remove them later after the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could just not remove items from the array.

Use a fixed size array instead (large enough to store all the items you need) and flag as canceled the items you don't want to render anymore, you could reuse those flagged slots later.

Or you could directly overwrite the elements if the domain of your problem allows it.

[EDIT]

Some more considerations in response to the comments:

The evaluations of additional flag are computations stable in time, meaning that you can foresee how much time they will need and see if they fit the frame to render at a certain frame rate. `Array.splice` on the other hand could trigger **garbage collection** and that could be **some order of magnitude** longer than other language control flow constructs.

**Garbage collection** is an intensive task and should be avoided at all costs in the main loop of a game to achieve a fluid framerate. There are some resources and other questions here on SO which elaborate on this point, for example: http://buildnewgames.com/garbage-collector-friendly-code/

Comment: This is a valid alternative approach, but it implies that there'll be some evaluating of these additional flags prior to reuse. Which also implies they'll have to be declared and set. If OP's experiencing performance issues with a simple splice then I think there are other considerations to make.

Comment: This is a valid approach to the problem, and suits my scenario. My alternative was to mark all platforms to be deleted and then batch splice them when the number reaches say 5.

Comment: The evaluations of additional flag are computations stable in time, splice on the other hand could trigger *garbage collection* and *that* is what is some order of magnitude longer than the other stuff and must be avoided at all costs in the mainloop of a game.

Comment: Good explanation about computation time and avoiding risks in time-critical parts!